# Regenerating all flask-sessions without logout the users

Tags: python, session, flask

Basically what I want to do is to regenerate every session with some new set of keys without having users to log in again. How can I do this?

**edited** for clarity

So let's assume we are using Redis as a backend for sessions and keeping cookies of it on the client-side. Cookie just consists of the session id. This session id corresponds to a session on the Redis. After we have initialized Session by writing Session(APP) in our application, for every request context, we can fetch the session of the current user by

```
from flask import session
```

After admin changes some general settings on the application, I am willing to regenerate the session of every current user which can be seen just for the current user by again

```
from flask import session
```

This is as far as I know.

For example, let's say there is a value on the user's session determined as

```
session['arbitrary_key'] = not_important_database_function()
```

After admin changes some stuff at application, I need to reload a key on the current user's session by

```
session['arbitrary_key'] = not_important_database_function()
```

Because after changes admin made, it will yield a different value. After that, I am changing `session.modified` as true. What I want to learn is how can I change the `arbitrary_key` on sessions of EVERY USER. Because I am lacking information on how to fetch every session and change them from Flask.

If I delete the sessions from Redis, users are required to reauthenticate. I don't want them to reauthenticate. I just want back-end sessions to be changed because I use some information inside of the user's session which needs to be fetched from Redis so I do not have to call                            `not_important_database_function` for every request.

I hope this is enough information for you to at least NOT answer but also NOT downvote so I can continue to seek a solution for my problem.

I am not sharing code snippets because no code snippet is helpful for the case in my opinion.

Comment: is the return value of `not_important_database_function()` the same for all users, or different on a per user basis (after the admin has made changes)?

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather old but it looks like many developers are interested in the answer. There are several approaches which come to mind:

### 1. Lazy calculations

You need a way to differentiate old and new session values. For example, storing version number in session. Then you can force clients to update their sessions when they are on your resource:

```
CURRENT_VERSION = '1.2.3'

@app.route('/some_route')
def some_handler():
    if session.get('version', '0.0.0') < CURRENT_VERSION:
        session['arbitrary_key'] = not_important_database_function()
        session['version'] = CURRENT_VERSION
```

**Pros:** The method is easy to implement and it is agnostic to the way of storing session data (database, user-agent, etc.)

**Cons:** Session data is not updated instantly after deploy. You have to give up that some users' session data may not be updated at all.

### 2. Session storage update

You need to make some kind of a database migration for session storage. It is backend-dependable and will look different for different storages. For Redis it may look like this:

```
import json
import redis

r = redis.Redis()  # Your connection settings here
for key in r.scan_iter():
    raw_value = r.get(key)
    session = json.loads(raw_value)
    session['arbitrary_key'] = not_important_database_function()
    r.set(key, json.dumps(session))
```

**Pros:** Session data for all users will be updated right after your service deployment.

**Cons:** The method implementations differ for different storages. It is not applicable if all session data is stored in user-agents.

### 3. Dropping session data

It is still an option though it is clearly stated in the question that you need to keep the users logged in. It may be a part of the policy of deploying new application versions: session key is regenerated on application deployment and all user sessions are invalidated.

**Pros:** You don't need to implement any logic to set new user session values.

**Cons:** There are no new user session values, the data is just wiped out.